# Embed Power BI dashboard tile and make it auto update

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In the Power BI dashboard all the tiles are auto updating when the dataset changes (rows are added), but If I embed a tile in an iframe in my own web page, the tile is not auto updating. Can it be done? Is it possible to have an embedded tile auto updating?

To embed the tile I followed these instructions:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-tile-load-tile-iframe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently confirmed with the product team that this feature is not currently supported with the tile API. It's on the roadmap to support this feature (auto-update of real-time tiles) but I don't believe they have shared an estimate on timing.

I would recommend you post this suggestion to https://ideas.powerbi.com and ask co-workers to vote.